# Explode function not in exploded character

Tags: php, string, explode

I am looking for an `explode` type function that will explode a string by characters but also take a list of characters to ignore if the character is within them.

For example:

```
$str = "hello, this is, a test 'some, string' thanks";
explode_func($str, ",", "'");
```

This would explode `$str` by `,` but ignore any `,` within `'`

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => this is
    [2] => a test
    [3] => thanks
)
```

Another example would be:

```
$str = "hello, this is, a test (some, string) thanks";
explode_func($str, ",", "()");
```

This would explode `$str` by `,` but ignore any `,` between `(` and `)` to get the same output.

Any ideas?

Comment: how would it handle `hello my name is 'b'r'i'a'n"` ?:) Seems like a regexp problem anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[str_getcsv()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$str = "hello, this is, a test 'some, string' thanks";
$array = str_getcsv($str, ",", "'");
```

which should give:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => this is
    [2] => a test 'some, string' thanks
)
```

Comment: @rudu - You mean there are people still running earlier versions? :)

Comment: hard to believe isn't it? (brushes one of the 5.2 servers under the carpet)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to remove the areas you want to ignore first.

```
function explode($str, $separator, $ignore_pattern) {
    $newStr = preg_replace($ignore_pattern, '', $str);
    return explode($separator, $str);
}
```

usage:

```
$str = "hello, this is, a test (some, string) thanks";
$array = explode($str, ',', '/\(.*?\)/');
```

Not tested but the theory is solid

Comment: For single quotes the preg_replace wouldnt work correctly is there was a quote within the quotes e.g. hello, this is, a test 'some, string\'s' thanks

Comment: If you were only looking to remove one chunk from the string you could use a greedy match. That would solve the quote problem.